# How to use GAPI to fetch current draft (and published) version of an extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, google-api-js-client

I'm developing a rolling release Chrome extension, I have a build script that publish the extension for me, but I want to make sure it doesn't publish developer preview, here is how my project works:

- Commit developer preview, no version change, build script does nothing
- Commit release, version changed, build script uploads new version to the store
- Commit developer preview, no version change, build script check published version but that is not updated, so it builds and uploads the developer preview

Being able to know the version number of the draft (the version that is under review) will be the best way solve this issue, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that with the web store API.

The build script is in JavaScript (Node.js), does anyone know how to access draft version number?

The ultimate solution is to have a custom API hosted by myself that the build script can call to check what it just built, but I want avoid that if possible.

Comment: You should *always* change the version if you are releasing a different set of code. Version numbers allow everyone to exactly identify the code that is being used. Unless it is an *exact* copy of a prior version, the version number should always change when the code is released (to a larger internal audience, as a "developer preview", alpha, beta, full release, etc.). While Chrome extension versioning is relatively limited, you do have 4 dot-separated numbers to use. Pick a versioning scheme which allows you and your users to exactly identify what is being used.

Comment: @Makyen As I am the only developer for most of the time, changing version number every time is wasting time. Also there can be multiple developer preview releases per minute as I do one commit per issue. I'm currently using a custom callback server until I get GAPI working...